# Way to return True/False with rails api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, api, rest, return-value

i need to create a method, which gets called by a local application with two parameters. how can i return true or false then? with xml? my method looks like this:

```
def check_license
  app_id = params[:id]
  app_sn = params[:sn]

  @license = License.find_by_id(app_id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @license.app_serial == app_sn
      # should return true here
   else
     # should return false here
   end
  end
end
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to decide with format your other internal application will call this application. Popular (and sane) formats are xml or json.

Then, in your controller, you need to render a response in each of those formats:

```
resp = @license.app_serial == app_sn
respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => resp }
   format.xml do
      if resp
        head :ok
      else
        render :xml => resp, :status => 403 # that's a failed authentication response
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can just use:

```
def check_license
  app_id = params[:id]
  app_sn = params[:sn]

  @license = License.find_by_id(app_id)

  @license.app_serial == app_sn
end
```

The last line in a ruby method will be the return value, so method here will return the result of that last relational statement: either true or false.

You don't need `respond_to |format|` if you're giving the same response for all formats, which I'd guess you are, given that you're returning a boolean.

Comment: thanks. and how do i get remove the "Template is missing" error when browsing to the url?

Comment: See my answer. Rails will `render` a template by default. You may need to instruct Rails to `render` an object directly, rather than with a template. Use `render :json => value.to_json`.

Answer (score 2):

```
# if you can use json:
licensed = @license.app_serial == app_sn
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :json => licensed.to_json }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  respond_to do |format|
    @license.app_serial == app_sn
   end
```

Rails will automatically return the result of the last line executed.